# Laravel cast JSON property as ENUM

Tags: php, laravel, enums

I know Enum support is fairly new to Laravel, but i'm wondering if anyone has figured out a way to cast a JSON property as an enum yet.

Lets say I have a JSON object stored against my user model, in a column called `settings` like this, that is casted as an `ArrayObject`.

```
{"role":"CEO","user_level":1}
```

I want to be able to cast the `user_level` property as an enum.

In a perfect world, this is how my `App\Models\User` model would look

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

//Enums
use App\Enums\User\UserLevel as UserLevelEnum;

//Facades
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\AsArrayObject;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
    */
    protected $casts = [
        'settings' => AsArrayObject::class,
        'settings->user_level' => UserLevelEnum::class
    ];
}
```

So that when I access the property like `$user->settings['user_level']` it returns the `App\Enums\User\UserLevel` enum.

Has anyone figured out a way to do this yet or knows if this is even possible?

Comment: I never saw someone asking or using this type of cast. I checked the Laravel 10.x docs and mentions nothing about this. I never had to attempt this, so I think it is not possible to define `'settings->user_level' => UserLevelEnum::class`, you will have to find another solution

Comment: Yeah I didnt see anything about it in the documentation either, but there is a lot of functionality hidden in Laravel that is not documented that people seem to figure out. Thought its worth a go to see if anyone figured it

Comment: Yeah, that is true. I currently don't have a Laravel installation, but what I 99% of the time do is literally check the source code and find it myself, can't do that now, sorry

Comment: Good point, i'll take a look and see if I can spot anything!